# Java - MouseEvent - isMetaDown - meta not working / what is meta?

Tags: java, mouseevent

for a project i have to work with a given class that starts actions by specific Events.
One of those actions is started by clicking the "meta"-key.

This is the query which checks this event. mevent is a object of the class MouseEvent.

```
if (this.mevent.isMetaDown())
```

sry for the question, i feel totally stupid about it.
i am not an english or american man and i dont know which key the meta key is.
of course i googled for it, but did not found the related one for german.

My question is now, which key is the "meta"-key or how can ich make the isMetaDown event make true?
I tried a lot of keys (ctrl, alt, altgr, shift, space) on my keyboards and clicked on everything on my mouse but the result of isMetaDown is allways false...

Best Regards and thank you in Advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key

Comment: hi khelwood, thank you for the link. i had allready found this page but the mentioned specific "meta"-key is not available at todays keyboards. At https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys it is mentioned that the meta-key is emulated by alt or altgr but those are also not working for me. The method says always that it is false

Comment: Not exactly "not available". Mac keyboards have a command ⌘ key which reads as meta for input events. Windows keyboards have a Windows key that can be used as meta, but probably depends on context and preferences.

Comment: ok, thanks for that information. But how can i make the event make true for me? i dont have an mac and the keys on my windows keyboard do not trigger the event. can i define in my java program for example the ctrl key to be a meta-key? so that everybody else who will use the program does not have the same problem.

Comment: Why would you not just use `isControlDown` instead of `isMetaDown`?

Comment: the event i am waiting for is in a class that i can not modifiy. it is the updateScene Method in the PickTranslateBehavior class of the java3d framework. and in case of the task i am working at, i have to use the picktranslatebehaviour class... Otherwise i would change the methods you mentioned immediately :D